# Устраняем неясности в правилах и словах: словарь слов, требующих толкования

Tags: предложение, правила, русский-язык

Все слова условно можно разделить на два вида:

1. не требуют толкования (однозначные);
2. требуют толкования (неоднозначные).

Примеры однозначных слов: вопрос, ответ, сообщение, голос, удаление, править и т.д.

Примеры неоднозначных слов: "нормы", уважение, доброта, помощь, добродетель, "культура", доброжелательность, терпение и т.п. (взято с https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct)

Много сложностей у участников возникает в следствие наличия и толкования как раз таки неоднозначных слов, которые присутствуют в правилах, справке и других  основополагающих сообщения, на которых строится само сообщество площадок StackExchange и в частности StackOverflow на русском.

В связи с вышесказанным, предлагаю составить список слов (общий ответ), используемых в правилах, справке и других важных разделах ruSO и Meta с целью дальнейшего уточнения по каждому из них, дабы по-возможности избавиться от личностной составляющей правоприменительного поведения каждым из участников.

Comment: Поддерживаю вопрос. У нас, помнится, были реальные разногласия по поводу значения слова «агрессивный», в частности, модсоставу хотелось считать «пассивную агрессию» (то есть, «фигу в кармане») разновидностью агрессии — и банить за неё.

Answer (score 5):

> Я никогда не отдам Джозефа! Только он один может составить контракт с единственно возможным истолкованием.И хотя этот его талант мне еще не требовался, однажды он мне может пригодиться.
>
> [Мандерлей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9) (2003)

Не согласен с предпосылкой. Нет слов, которые не требуют толкования и значение которых однозначно. Все слова относятся ко второму виду.

Особенно странно видеть в списке «однозначных» слов слова «вопрос» и «ответ», учитывая что немалая часть правил посвящена тому что можно считать вопросом, а что нет. Большинство споров между участниками по поводу правил возникает как раз из-за несогласия по поводу того что является вопросом/ответом на Stack Overflow.

Формулировку (*Шишков, прости*) правил лучше уточнять по мере необходимости, в случае если у участников возникнут проблемы с их истолкованием. На примере будет понятно какие именно необходимы изменения и у сообщества будет возможность их обсудить. Для этого и нужна Мета, часто популярные ответы здесь выполняют роль общепринятой трактовки правил, на которую могут опираться модераторы и пользователи.

Кроме того, полагаю что часть положений правил намеренно оставлены размытыми, чтобы у сообщества и модераторов была возможность принятия решений по ситуации. Например, нельзя составлять полный список всех недоброжелательных поступков. Проще дать несколько примеров, а в остальном полагаться на то, что Компания, модераторы и сообщество сами определят что считать, а что не считать допустимым.

Т.о. составление «толкового словаря» не видится уместным. Большинство толкований слов (у Ожегова дается четыре толкования для слова «вопрос») не относятся к правилам, а замена отдельных слов не принесет однозначного улучшения.

P.S. Нормы поведения скоро будут изменяться, правила скорее всего тоже.
P.P.S. Когда-то давно у Stack Overflow нормы поведения состояли по сути из одной фразы «Be nice» («Будь хорошим»). Уточнение этих нехитрых норм происходило через диалог на Мете. Последние изменения в нормы поведения, а именно, резкая манера в которой они были объявлены, вызвали у многих членов сообщества (англоязычного по крайней мере) ностальгию по старому-доброму времени.

Comment: Вопрос — первое сообщение на странице /questions/\d+. Все остальные — ответы.

Answer (score -5):

- Доброжелательность
- Культура